# C++ Запуск внешней программы и вывод результата

Tags: c++, windows

Задача заключается в том что нужно отправить данные на сайт посредством GET запроса.
Для выполнения запроса использую следующую программу
[CURL](https://curl.haxx.se/)

Отправляю запрос следующим образом:

C++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string GetStdoutFromCommand(string cmd) {
    string data;
    FILE * stream;
    const int max_buffer = 256;
    char buffer[max_buffer];
    //cmd.append(" 2>&1");

    stream = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    if (stream) {
    while (!feof(stream))
    if (fgets(buffer, max_buffer, stream) != NULL) data.append(buffer);
    pclose(stream);
    }
    return data;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string keys = "--url https://example.com/load.html?namepc=MyPC&action=set_action";
    string ls = GetStdoutFromCommand("C:\\curl\\curl.exe "+keys);

    cout << "LS: " << ls << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить данную проблему?

> "action" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой
>   программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Что такое  `GetStdoutFromCommand`? Приведите полностью код, воспроизводящий проблему. А вообще я подозреваю, что вокруг url не хватает кавычек.

Comment: @VTT, обновил пост с кодом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заверните параметр в кавычки.

```
string keys = "--url \"https://example.com/load.html?namepc=MyPC&action=set_action\"";
```